# Check every value of an ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I'm parsing XML with ElementTree in python and I have to check if every float in my tree are with "," instead of "." but I don't know how reach every child of my tree which is created from a +100K line of xml so very big.

it's a very short sample but :

```
<example tr="3,1">
 <test>2.1</test>
 <stack> 
  <nb>2,5</nb> 
  <nb>5.1</nb>
 </stack>
</example>
```

I would like check if any value which is a float is with a comma or a point. My issue is to reach every value of a tree with any tree.

So far I tried this :

```
tree = ET.parse(chemin, parser=LineNumberingParser())
root = tree.getroot()
float_text_info = []
for element in root.getiterator():
    if element is not None:
         element_value = element.text.strip()
         if element_value and re.findall('\d+[\.|,]\d+', element_value):
             float_text_info.append(element_value)
```

Comment: can you provide sample input and what you try?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your sample rather than answering in the comments. Can you also show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Okay .. I'm into algorithm to reach every value of my tree but I don't know if it's the good idea because it's energy vore.. maybe something is already existing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By `ElementTree` we can do in following way:

1. Create root object of `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element`.
2. Iterate every element from a input by `getiterator()` method.
3. Use `re` to check text is number seperated by `. or ,`.
4. If yes then add to result list.
5. Display result list.

**Demo:**

```
>>> data = """
... <example tr="3,1">
...  <test>2.1</test>
...  <stack> 
...   <nb>2,5</nb> 
...   <nb>5.1</nb>
...  </stack>
... </example> """
>>> 
>>> 
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as PARSER
>>> import re
>>>            
... root = PARSER.fromstring(data)
>>> 
>>> float_text_info = []
>>> for element in root.getiterator():
...     element_value = element.text.strip()
...     if element_value and re.findall('\d+[\.|,]\d+', element_value):
...         float_text_info.append(element_value)
...         
... 
>>> print "float_text_info:", float_text_info
float_text_info: ['2.1', '2,5', '5.1']
```

Do **Exception handling** when there is comment in XML.

```
try:
    element_value = element.text.strip()
 except:
     continue
```

Or:

best to check element is None or not.

```
for element in root.getiterator():
    if element is not None and element.text is not None:
        element_value = element.text.strip()
        if element_value and re.findall('\d+[\.|,]\d+', element_value):
            float_text_info.append(element_value)
```

**Note:**

1. This is basic code, you can modify according to you algorithm condition.
2. Use `lxml` library to parse xml data.
3. Do necessary Exception Handling.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! so it's works indeed for this small tree but mine is way bigger and more difficult so it don't work .. I think I have to browse every value of my tree to do it. Why should I use `lxml` ? I'm working with industrial norm wich oblige me to work with `ElementTree`

Comment: nope, it work for big document too. where script fails for big document? `lxml` is more powerful then `ElementTree`

Comment: It says to me :
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "VerifReports.py", line 89, in <module>
    element_value = element.text.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'`

Comment: yes, need to handle exception when there is comment statement in XML content.  updated code. plz check and let me know.

Comment: I've got the same exception again !

Comment: no, same exception should not come, Pass me input file and your code? vivekbsable@gmail.com

Comment: My input file is from my company so it's confidientiel ... I copied your code and I'm using a good root so I don't know ..

Comment: its fine. I am not going to do anything with ur input.  pass me your code atleast.

Comment: It's not about you it's about my company. Yep i updated my request

Comment: :) `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'` this exception is coming? I do not think, can u check once again. might be different exception.

Comment: I can affirm you to 100% that the same exception is coming :
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "VerifReports.py", line 90, in <module>
    element_value = element.text.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'`

Comment: just add one more condition in if loop-->  `if element is not None and element.text is not None: ` . And let me know this is working or not.

Comment: Men you're so nice it's working perfectly thank you very much !